# Symfony2 Case sensitive Unique validation on 2 fields

Tags: php, postgresql, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

beginner to symfony, i have a calss institutes

```
class Institutes {
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $city;
}
```

what i want the name of the institute name unique in each city. In other words preventing users to input multiple institutes in same city.
I know that there is a `unique entity` option but that can't help. because institute name can be same in different cities but not in the `same city`.

Some thing i read about custom validation using repository classes, but don't konw how will it work.
e.g

```
      name       |   city   | valid  |
-----------------+-------------------+
DHQ Hospital    | Attock    | t      |
dhq Hospital    | Attock    | f      | already exists in the city
dHQ HospITal    | Attock    | f      | already exists in the city
DHQ Hospital    | Islamabad | t      |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UniqueEntity` validator, it can check that a combination of fields, not just a single field is unique. In your case, you could use (using annotations):

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = {"name", "city"})
 */
class Institutes
{
...
}
```

Comment: I have used it, but what about `case sensitive uniqueness of name`

Comment: I am not really sure, but I think that if you configured your database to be case insensitive (for example, using the utf8_general_ci collation, ci is for case insensitive) it should be already working

Comment: I have tried, but this will not allow me to enter the same institute name for different city

Comment: is there any way to execute my custom query or view to check this validation and return true or false result. I have done this stuff in Django but don't know how to do this in symfony2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91966/discussion-between-mtaqi-and-carlos-granados).